# MySQL GROUP BY query drastically slow down when after data reaches a certain amount

Tags: mysql

I need help finding out why the following query that aggregates peoples' responses by "item" slows down considerably after the data being aggregated reaches a certain size.

```
select
  t1.item,
  count(t1.val) as count,
  round(avg(t1.resp), 2) as mean,
  round(std(t1.resp), 2) as std
from
  person_response as t1
  join person_info as t2
    on t1.person_id = t2.id
where
  t1.resp between 1 and 5
  and t2.is_valid = 1
  and (t2.attr1, t2.attr2) in ((?, ?), ...)
  and t2.attr3 in (?, ...)
  and t1.item in (?, ...)
group by t1.item
;
```

t1 has about 15 million rows and t2 has about 200,000 rows. All columns involved in the query are indexed. If the WHERE clause captures under 50,000 rows, execution is generally under 100 ms. If the WHERE clause captures 138,665 rows, execution is under 500 ms. But when I extend the WHERE clause to capture 150,685 rows, execution takes considerably longer at 3 m 40 s 366 ms. Nearly 4 minutes!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE t1` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE t2` outputs. "All columns involved in the query are indexed." That statement doesn't mean much if they are just single column indexes.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I needed a single-column index on t1.item. It had a multi-column index that was doing nothing for the query.